# graphics.h in vs code

Tags: c, bgi

[image]I tried to run following code: using tdm-gcc32bit compiler in terminal typing `./test` then it runs successfully.

code:

```
#include<graphics.h>

int main()
{
    int gd=DETECT,gm;
    
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,(char*)"");
    
//  left defines distance of pixel from left to circumference, top id distance from top of screen and radius is simply radius of circle
    int left=200,top=150,radius=15;  
    
    circle(left,top,radius);
//  circle()
    
    getch();
    
    closegraph();

return 0;

}
```

But when I press *runcode* button it gives error:
**C:/Program Files (x86)/
Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GCC-64/
bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/
9.2.0/../../../../
x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
skipping incompatible C:/Program
Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/
TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/
x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../
libbgi.a when searching for -lbgi**

CAN ANYONE HERE TO FIX THIS ERROR?[image]

Comment: That library is old, unmaintained, and doesn't reflect how graphics have been done in the last 20 or so years. Whatever class you're taking or whatever tutorial you're following, that teaches you about it, should be looked at as highly suspicious.

Comment: Are you possibly compiling a 64-bit executable using the same old 32-bit library? Not going to work.

Comment: How do you build your program in the first case where you can run `./test`? What options did you provide to the linker? You must tell VSC to add the same options. Probably via `tasks.json` file

Comment: 1. this is not `[graphics]` but `[BGI]` you should retag also which BGI it is? 2. `vs code` ? your error suggest mingw32 Embarcadero GCC so which is it? 3. your error suggest 64bit target are you sure your BGI is 64 bit too? I know only of 32 and 16 bit versions ... also is it matching your OS?